# how can I mount a windows share with rw access?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, file-sharing, cifs

The question is in the title.

Here is what I tried but the folder is read only.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=maazza,domain=MYDOMAIN //192.168.123.2/company-files /mnt/test
```

I am on debian jessie.

I read something about forcing an user id and a group id but I do not know how I can find them on windows or how I can set the in the mount.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the *local* UID using mount options, example below. You can find out your UID by running the `id -u` command.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=maazza,domain=MYDOMAIN,uid=1000 //192.168.123.2/company-files /mnt/test
```

This will essentially map and override all files within that share to your own local Linux UID, regardless of remote ownership. However, if your domain user doesn't have write access, you still won't be able to write to the share.

If you require full permissions management, you will need to join your Linux machine to your Windows domain.

Answer (score 0):

This works extremely well on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core):

```
sudo mount -t cifs --rw -o username=myusername,domain=MYDOMAIN,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),forceuid,forcegid //serverhostname/home$/myusername /home/myusername/smb_drives/H
```